# Different content types, different permissions

Tags: drupal, permissions

On my website, users have the possibility to upload different kinds of content (theme1, theme2, theme3,...). I also have different kind of user roles (author1, author2, author3,...). Every user role has only permissions to make, edit and delete one specific kind of content. I can do it the rough way and adding 8 different kinds of content types and 8 different user roles and make myself a complete mess while composing all the right roles.

I was wondering if there was a more easier way to do this in Drupal 7. The old D6-supported [Upload Permissions per Content Type](http://drupal.org/project/upload_perm_per_type) would have been ideal, but unfortunately, there was never a D7 version released.
Does anyone have an idea how to do this so I can just configure some kind of matrix to define all the user-roles and their permissions?

Answer (score 1):

The "Content Type: Extras" module looks like it might help.

http://drupal.org/project/content_type_extras